# In Google sheet, How to get multiple 'where' including the date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with data (named datasheet), which contains bookings/reservations. I want to create one search cell, in which I can give ´search input´  This search input can be a date DATE, ZIP code or a part of a Name.
For finding the date I use:

```
select (  where K = date '"&TEXT(S2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR B = ' " &S2& " ' )
```

Column K contains reservation dates
Cell S2  is the search input Cell

The problem is, when the input isn't a date, it comes with an Error.

I've tried to make a cell where it depends on 'ISDATE' create a what fits with the given input. However, due to the "quotes, this seems not possible  (I've tried to use char(34).

```
cell X1 =>    =if(isdate(date query);non date query)
=QUERY(datasheet!A1:R1500; '&X1&')
```

My question is. 
Can I create a search filter  (one cell to enter) of  'datasheet' (rows with data) on any given element in this data sheet? 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different types of data need different "string structure" in query. So if you need one input for your purpose you need to check first what kind of data was entered.

Below you have step by step approach. For explanation purpose I split this into steps - you can pack all together in one formula in your sheet.

### 1. Checking type of data

I assume that you only have strings, numbers and dates (if you need more, e.g. booleans - you have to expand based on this approach):

[image]

```
=iF(ISTEXT(E2)=TRUE;"txt";IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2)=TRUE;ISDATE(E2)=TRUE);"date";"num"))
```

### 2. Preparing string for Query

[image]

```
=if(E3="txt";"'"&E2&"'";IF(E3="num";E2;" date '"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"))
```

### 3. Building final Query

[image]

```
=QUERY(A:C;"select * where (A="&G2&" or B = "&G2&" or C="&G2&")";0)
```

### Link to working Sheet:

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v9V89cmX2CS_L_IyMU1p8LQUoKvH4Ktfb7Yb4klnjls/edit#gid=0)

Is this fulfil your needs?

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot. Good detailed answer, thank you for this.

Comment: Glad I could help :)